# printf “%6.1f” 12.3456 printf”|%6s%8.2f|” hello 12.2456) explanation

Tags: bash

The following code returns the following values accordingly :

```
printf “%6.1f”  12.3456       printf”|%6s%8.2f|” hello  12.2456)
_ _ 12.3                      |_hello_ _ _ 12.25|
```

The question is what does each character of the code mean and why does it return these values?

Comment: `printf` in Javascript ?

Comment: sorry my mistake. It's bash

Comment: That code is seriously garbled. It has the wrong kind of quotes, missing space(s), an unmatched close parenthesis... Please edit to include an accurate copy.

Comment: I copied it exactly how it was in the task. If you know how to make it look right please help

Comment: No, you have not copied it exactly. We don't have access to "the task" (is this homework?) so we can't see how it's supposed to look.

Answer (score 3):

They seem homeworks and the code is... read this short tutorial which should help you solve it https://linuxconfig.org/bash-printf-syntax-basics-with-examples

As a hint: `printf “%5.2f”  100.1555` Which means:

- **printf** function that prints text to console
- **%** print an argument
- **5.2f** format of the argument

  - **5** print integer part with 5 characters, if the integer part has less than 5 characters, fill it with spaces, if it has more it will NOT cut it
  - **.** separates the integer and decimal format syntax
  - **2** print decimal part with 2 characters, if the integer part has less than 2 characters, fill it with spaces, if it has more cut it to meet 2 characters
  - **f** the argument is of type float. *For more info https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_30.htm*
  - **100.1555** argument

The result would be: `<space><space>100.15` (if you count the characters, there are 5 characters at the left of the dot, and 2 at the right --> 5.2)

For `printf “%6.2f”  100.1555` result would be: `<space><space><space>100.15`

For `printf “%6.3f”  100.1555` result would be: `<space><space><space>100.155`

For `printf “%1.3f”  100.1555` result would be: `100.155` (integer part is never cut)